# Can someone explain this c++ program using vector and algorithm?

Tags: string, vector, data-structures, stl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

string buildRWord(string word) {
    string rword = "";
    vector<string> wrd;
    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); ++i)
        wrd.push_back(word.substr(i,1));
    reverse(word.begin(), word.end());
    for(int i = 0; i < word.size(); ++i)
       rword += word[i];
    return rword;
}

int main()
{
    string aword;
    cout << "Enter a word: ";
    cin >> aword;
    string raword = buildRWord(aword);
    if (raword == aword)
        cout << aword << " is a palindrome."
             << endl;
    else
        cout << aword << " is not a palindrome."
             << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This program works perfectly but I don't know how it exactly works I mean the internal step by step operation. Can someone explain this code? I need a detailed explanation on the global function part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's checking whether a given string is a palindrome or not.Vectors are nothing but arrays with the added feature of dynamic size. Here reverse() is called on the String with the parameters specifying the start of the string and the end of the string, the reverse function reverses the order of the elements in the range [first, last). The program is using that, you could have used the vector wrd also. If you are not going to use it, you may consider removing those lines concerning the vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
/* On top you have added all the library functions, vector data structure is like array but its size can dynamically change, iostream allows you to accept input from user, alogorithm avails all the other necessary algorithmic functions for the purpose.
*/


using namespace std;

string buildRWord(string word) {// The variable word gets aword in the call in the main function
    string rword = "";
    vector<string> wrd;// Declaring a vector variable
    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); ++i)
        wrd.push_back(word.substr(i,1));//pushing each character at the end of the vector using call to push_back, push_back always puts a new element at the end of the vector 
    reverse(word.begin(), word.end());// reverse the word
    for(int i = 0; i < word.size(); ++i)// adding the characters from word to rword, one at a time.
       rword += word[i];
    return rword;// returning rword
}

int main()
{
    string aword;
    cout << "Enter a word: ";
    cin >> aword;// Storing the input word in this String called aword
    string raword = buildRWord(aword);// Calling the function buildRWord on aWord
    if (raword == aword)// Checking for string equality
        cout << aword << " is a palindrome."// if equal is a palindrome.
             << endl;
    else
        cout << aword << " is not a palindrome."// if not equal is not a palindrome.
             << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes it should have been used, they used reverse function on the word instead. On first look I felt it may have been used , I have edited my answer to reflect that.